# jQuery Quiz save progress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, session-variables

I'm building a quiz for a client and they want it so if the user quits the quiz it will save their progress and allow them to continue where they left off when they return. The quiz it self will only be available to logged in users, so with that being said my question is what would be the best method to accomplish this? I was thinking about using a `SESSION` variable but that won't work because if the user closes the browser it will delete the save point, so is my only other method to do this is to use a database to store this info? Any advice on how I should approach this would be great and very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the data in a `$_SESSION` but immediately copy it to an SQL table every time you update it, or at least when they click quit.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense to just use session variables while they take the quiz and then save process once they hit quite, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cookies. That's what I would do, because then you would only get fully completed quizes in your database. Are you jumping from 1 question to another with a complete page refresh, or using jquery? If it's the second would, I would definitaly recommend cookies.

Comment: In the same vein as this, you may want to look into HTML5's [Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).  However, if you have to compensate for older browser's, then the Web Storage route might not be a good idea...